# Custom CSS Navigation Menu, no drop down

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

So I have a custom naviation menu that i'm trying to make, and I can't seem to get it working. I've included both my code and my css code. I have 3 sub menus, and on hover over the parent they should be displaying, but they are not.

Any ideas?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-padder">
    <a href="">Item 1</a>
    <a href="">Item 2</a>
    <li class="submenu">
    <a href="">Subitem 1</a>
    <a href="">Subitem 2</a>
    </li>
    <a href="">Item 3</a>
    <li class="submenu">
    <a href="">Subitem 1</a>
    <a href="">Subitem 2</a>
    </li>
    <a href="">Item 4</a>
    <li class="submenu">
    <a href="">Subitem 1</a>
    <a href="">Subitem 2</a>
    </li>   
    <a href="">Item 5</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.menu {
    background-image: url('img/menu.jpg');
    width: 1000px;
}
.menu-padder {
    padding:5px;
}
.menu a {
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu a:hover {
    padding:5px;
    color:yellow;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.submenu {
    display:none;
    padding:0px;
}
a:hover .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not the right way to create a menu, you need to change your HTML and some change in your CSS:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/xwUGy/)

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-padder">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Item 2</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><<a href="">Subitem 1</a></li>
                    <li><<a href="">Subitem 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Item 3</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><<a href="">Subitem 1</a></li>
                    <li><<a href="">Subitem 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Item 4</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><<a href="">Subitem 1</a></li>
                    <li><<a href="">Subitem 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

but if you want to have your HTML just use this selector:

```
a:hover + .submenu, .submenu:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

and change this style:

```
.submenu {
    display:none;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;  /* or something else */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/xwUGy/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS adjacent selector:

```
a:hover + .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `<ul>`
The html code should be like

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the css like

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

In your code try this:

```
 <ul>
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="submenu">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="">Subitem 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Subitem 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That appears to be HTML5, since most of the visitors using this site aren't using HTML5 compliant browsers, I'm trying to avoid using that. I would like to stick with the code I currently have, I am able to get the desired result using 1 div and adding .menu:hover .submenu instead of a:hover .submenu. Are you telling me a sub menu is not possible with the code I currently have?

Comment: Use the css exemple that I gave and the last code. I'm making in JSFiddle.. wait a moment

Comment: Check the answer of @Mohsen.. I've created the same solution

Comment: The JS fiddle is exactly what I am looking for this has perfectly resolved my issue. Thank you very much!